# Gstreamer: rtsp server stalls with v4l2h264enc on raspberry pi 4

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspberry-pi4, v4l2

I'm writing a rtsp application using gst-rtsp-server on raspberry pi 4 and Linux MATE 64bit SO. I use Gstreamer version 1.20.3.
Starting from `test-appsrc.cpp` example I tried the following pipeline:
`appsrc name=mysrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96`
and it works as expected: a VLC client is able to open and play the rtsp stream.
In the next step I tried to change the soft-h264encoder with `v4l2h264enc` element but it failed. The stream can be opened from a rtsp client but after about a second the server stalls and the stream stops.
With the same pipeline, if I change the appsrc with a `videotestsrc is-live=true` the streams works well also with `v4l2h264enc`.
I attach my code:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>
#include <iostream>         

typedef struct
{
  gboolean white;
  GstClockTime timestamp;
} MyContext;


/* called when we need to give data to appsrc */
static void
need_data (GstElement * appsrc, guint unused, MyContext * ctx)
{
  GstBuffer *buffer;
  guint size;
  GstFlowReturn ret;

  size = 640 * 480 * 3;

  buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate (NULL, size, NULL);

  /* this makes the image black/white */
  gst_buffer_memset (buffer, 0, ctx->white ? 0xff : 0x0, size);

  ctx->white = !ctx->white;

  /* increment the timestamp every 1/30 second */
  GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = ctx->timestamp;
  GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, 30);
  ctx->timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer);

  g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
  gst_buffer_unref (buffer);
}

/* called when a new media pipeline is constructed. We can query the
 * pipeline and configure our appsrc */
static void
media_configure (GstRTSPMediaFactory * factory, GstRTSPMedia * media,
    gpointer user_data)
{
  GstElement *element, *appsrc;
  MyContext *ctx;

  /* get the element used for providing the streams of the media */
  element = gst_rtsp_media_get_element (media);

  /* get our appsrc, we named it 'mysrc' with the name property */
  appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name_recurse_up (GST_BIN (element), "mysrc");

  /* this instructs appsrc that we will be dealing with timed buffer */
  gst_util_set_object_arg (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "format", "time");

  ctx = g_new0 (MyContext, 1);
  ctx->white = FALSE;
  ctx->timestamp = 0;
  /* make sure ther datais freed when the media is gone */
  g_object_set_data_full (G_OBJECT (media), "my-extra-data", ctx,
      (GDestroyNotify) g_free);

  /* install the callback that will be called when a buffer is needed */
  g_signal_connect (appsrc, "need-data", (GCallback) need_data, ctx);
  gst_object_unref (appsrc);
  gst_object_unref (element);
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstRTSPServer *server;
  GstRTSPMountPoints *mounts;
  GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  /* create a server instance */
  server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();

  /* get the mount points for this server, every server has a default object
   * that be used to map uri mount points to media factories */
  mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points (server);

  /* make a media factory for a test stream. The default media factory can use
   * gst-launch syntax to create pipelines.
   * any launch line works as long as it contains elements named pay%d. Each
   * element with pay%d names will be a stream */
  factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();
  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,
    "( appsrc is-live=true name=mysrc ! video/x-raw, format=(string)RGB, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! videoconvert ! v4l2h264enc ! video/x-h264, level=(string)4 ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");

  /* notify when our media is ready, This is called whenever someone asks for
   * the media and a new pipeline with our appsrc is created */
  g_signal_connect (factory, "media-configure", (GCallback) media_configure,
      NULL);

  /* attach the test factory to the /test url */
  gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory (mounts, "/test", factory);

  /* don't need the ref to the mounts anymore */
  g_object_unref (mounts);

  /* attach the server to the default maincontext */
  gst_rtsp_server_attach (server, NULL);

  /* start serving */
  g_print ("stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test\n");
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  return 0;
}
```

If I set GST_DEBUG=3 the warnings are:

```
0:00:02.615073094 19903 0xffffb4003860 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4524:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2h264enc0:src> Failed to probe pixel aspect ratio with VIDIOC_CROPCAP: Invalid argument
0:00:02.623833585 19903 0xffffb4002cc0 WARN              video-info video-info.c:191:validate_colorimetry: color matrix RGB is only supported with RGB format, ENCODED is not
0:00:02.623935528 19903 0xffffb4002cc0 WARN              video-info video-info.c:515:gst_video_info_from_caps: invalid colorimetry, using default
0:00:02.624039211 19903 0xffffb4002cc0 WARN              video-info video-info.c:191:validate_colorimetry: color matrix RGB is only supported with RGB format, ENCODED is not
0:00:02.624080229 19903 0xffffb4002cc0 WARN              video-info video-info.c:515:gst_video_info_from_caps: invalid colorimetry, using default
0:00:02.641441749 19903 0xffffb4002cc0 WARN          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:842:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_start:<v4l2h264enc0:pool0:src> Uncertain or not enough buffers, enabling copy threshold
0:00:02.664285523 19903 0xaaab0ebfbcc0 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:4623:gst_rtsp_media_suspend: media 0xffffb40531d0 was not prepared
0:00:02.699610739 19903 0xffffb4003860 WARN                basesink gstbasesink.c:1249:gst_base_sink_query_latency:<multiudpsink0> warning: Pipeline construction is invalid, please add queues.
0:00:02.699724385 19903 0xffffb4003860 WARN                basesink gstbasesink.c:1249:gst_base_sink_query_latency:<multiudpsink0> warning: Not enough buffering available for  the processing deadline of 0:00:00.020000000, add enough queues to buffer  0:00:00.020000000 additional data. Shortening processing latency to 0:00:00.000000000.
0:00:02.700839235 19903 0xffffb0018120 WARN                basesink gstbasesink.c:1249:gst_base_sink_query_latency:<multiudpsink0> warning: Pipeline construction is invalid, please add queues.
0:00:02.700973381 19903 0xffffb0018120 WARN                basesink gstbasesink.c:1249:gst_base_sink_query_latency:<multiudpsink0> warning: Not enough buffering available for  the processing deadline of 0:00:00.020000000, add enough queues to buffer  0:00:00.020000000 additional data. Shortening processing latency to 0:00:00.000000000.
0:00:02.701649702 19903 0xffffb4003860 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3281:default_handle_message: 0xffffb40531d0: got warning Pipeline construction is invalid, please add queues. (../libs/gst/base/gstbasesink.c(1249): gst_base_sink_query_latency (): /GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstMultiUDPSink:multiudpsink0:
Not enough buffering available for  the processing deadline of 0:00:00.020000000, add enough queues to buffer  0:00:00.020000000 additional data. Shortening processing latency to 0:00:00.000000000.)
0:00:02.701869735 19903 0xffffb4003860 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3281:default_handle_message: 0xffffb40531d0: got warning Pipeline construction is invalid, please add queues. (../libs/gst/base/gstbasesink.c(1249): gst_base_sink_query_latency (): /GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstMultiUDPSink:multiudpsink0:
Not enough buffering available for  the processing deadline of 0:00:00.020000000, add enough queues to buffer  0:00:00.020000000 additional data. Shortening processing latency to 0:00:00.000000000.)
0:00:05.146471158 19903 0xffffb4003860 WARN                basesink gstbasesink.c:1249:gst_base_sink_query_latency:<multiudpsink0> warning: Pipeline construction is invalid, please add queues.
0:00:05.146598989 19903 0xffffb4003860 WARN                basesink gstbasesink.c:1249:gst_base_sink_query_latency:<multiudpsink0> warning: Not enough buffering available for  the processing deadline of 0:00:00.020000000, add enough queues to buffer  0:00:00.020000000 additional data. Shortening processing latency to 0:00:00.000000000.
0:00:05.147139461 19903 0xffffb4003860 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3281:default_handle_message: 0xffffb40531d0: got warning Pipeline construction is invalid, please add queues. (../libs/gst/base/gstbasesink.c(1249): gst_base_sink_query_latency (): /GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstMultiUDPSink:multiudpsink0:
Not enough buffering available for  the processing deadline of 0:00:00.020000000, add enough queues to buffer  0:00:00.020000000 additional data. Shortening processing latency to 0:00:00.000000000.)
0:00:14.123535590 19903 0xaaab0ebfbcc0 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:4935:gst_rtsp_media_set_state: media 0xffffb40531d0 was not prepared
```